# C#: How can I make my program click the links in emails?

Tags: c#, email, httpwebrequest, email-verification

I want my program to log in to the users email account with the information they provide and click on the emails and then click the links inside the email?

If you know how to do this in browser or httpwebrequest Im all ears. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of email accounts are they? POP3?

Comment: Given the kinds of emails most people get this may be some seriously destructive behavior. >_<

Comment: What's the purpose?  This sounds malicious!

Answer (score 0):

There is a library for .net called the html agility pack. You can find it at http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com it will help you to traverse the dom model of web pages easily. you can use a web browser control to work with the website or use the functiond in the html agility pack to work with the sure too.